# How can I suppress C++ warnings for a list of error codes in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

I've migrated a project from a very old version of Visual Studio to Visual Studio 2017.  I now get hundreds of warning messages that I know about and do not wish to see again.  I'd like to suppress warnings for certain codes while retaining any others.

Is there any way I suppress C++ warnings for a list of error codes in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Does this help?  [How to: Suppress Compiler Warnings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I saw that but didn't read carefully enough.  I'll try and report back.

Comment: Yes, that works but one has to enter the warning code without any leading alphabetic character.  Eg. C4244 should be entered as 4244.